# How to find a radio button element by value using Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, selenium-chromedriver

Until now I just did like:

```
val radioButton4: WebElement = driver.findElement(By.id("FieldsubCode2"))

radioButton4.click
```

but now I want to find element by value, this value:

[image]

So I want to go:

```
val radioButton4: WebElement = driver.findElement(By.value("3.2"))


radioButton4.click
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 14):

If you want to find only by value then use,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='3.2']"));
```

Answer (score 10):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='buttonName' and @value='3.2']"));
```

Answer (score 5):

```
driver.FindElement(By.cssSelector(input[type='radio'][value='3.2']));
```

Answer (score 4):

In python, it's

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='buttonName' and @value='3.2']")`

Comment: This does not work in the latest version and I have not found anything in the documentation that explains how to use it. Any suggestions?